# Get link and text using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to find the urls of a web page with specific `regex`. I used `scrapy` package in `python`. 
My code looks like this

```
name = 'testingcode'
start_urls = ['http://dinoopnair.blogspot.in/'] # urls from which the spider will start crawling
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'page/\d+']), follow=True), 
    # r'page/\d+' : regular expression for http://isbullsh.it/page/X URLs
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'\d{4}/\d{2}/\w+']), callback='parse_blogpost',follow=True)]
    # r'\d{4}/\d{2}/\w+' : regular expression for http://isbullsh.it/YYYY/MM/title URLs

def parse_blogpost(self, response):
    print response.url
```

It works fine. Now i want to get the text of the links also. 
For example

```
<a href="http://dinoopnair.blogspot.in/2014/07/facebook-search-and-elastic-search.html">facebook search and elastic search</a>
```

This is one of the article link satisfying our regex. I want to get the text "facebook search and elastic search" between the `a` tags.
How it is possible to find the text from `response` parameter of callback functon?

Comment: You can use the help of xpaths for extracting them

Comment: response has parameter response.url . Like that is there any method to find the text?

Comment: actually i am trying to find a general solution instead of providing the name of the tag or class name. if a link from parent url matches regex, print that link and the text between <a> tag instead of reading the contents of matched url.

Comment: then better you go for `BaseSpider` instead of `CrawlSpider`

Answer (score 1):

I think this will satisfy your needs,

```
class TestSpider(Spider): #inherit from Spider intead of CrawlSpider
        name = 'testingcode'
        start_urls = ['http://dinoopnair.blogspot.in/']

        def parse(self, response):
            base_selector = response.xpath('//h3[@class="post-title entry-title"]')
            for sel in base_selector:
               link = sel.xpath('./a/@href').extract()
               link_text = sel.xpath('./a/text()').extract()
               # clean the data
               link = link[0] if link else 'n/a'
               link_text = link_text[0].strip() if link else 'n/a'
               print link, link_text
```

**Edit**

generalized code,  since the user has several start-urls

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
# other codes here 

def parse(self, response):
    # change the regex accordingly
    links = response.xpath('//a').re(r'href=".*\d{4}/\d{2}/.*')
    for link in links:
        sell = Selector(text='<a '+link)
        link_text = sell.xpath('//a//text()').extract()
        url = sell.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
        link_text = ' '.join(link_text).strip() if link else 'n/a'
        url = url[0] if link else 'n/a'
        print(link_text, url)
```